# Cannot get wrapping of filter to compile

Tags: rust

I have the goal of wrapping an `Iterator<Item = rusb::Device<_>` to `Iterator<Item = LitraDevice>`. The latter contains specific implementation.

To make this work I tried the following code:

```rust
use std::iter::Filter;

use rusb;

const VENDOR: u16 = 0x046d;
const PRODUCT: u16 = 0xc900;

struct LitraDevice {
    dev: rusb::Device<rusb::GlobalContext>,
}

pub struct LitraDevices {
    unfiltered: rusb::DeviceList<rusb::GlobalContext>,
}

struct LitraDeviceIterator<'a> {
    it: Filter<rusb::Devices<'a, rusb::GlobalContext>, for<'r> fn(&'r rusb::Device<rusb::GlobalContext>) -> bool>,
}

impl LitraDevices {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let unfiltered = rusb::devices().unwrap();
        LitraDevices { unfiltered }
    }

    fn can_not_handle<'r>(dev: &'r rusb::Device<rusb::GlobalContext>) -> bool {
        let desc = dev.device_descriptor().unwrap();
        match (desc.vendor_id(), desc.product_id()) {
            (VENDOR, PRODUCT) => (),
            _ => return true,
        }
        match desc.class_code() {
            LIBUSB_CLASS_HID => return true, // Skip HID devices, they are handled directly by OS libraries
            _ => return false,
        }
    }

    pub fn iter<'a>(self) -> LitraDeviceIterator<'a> {
        let it = self.unfiltered.iter().filter(Self::can_not_handle);
        LitraDeviceIterator{
            it,
        }
    }
}

impl <'a> Iterator for LitraDeviceIterator<'a> {
    type Item = LitraDevice;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let n = self.it.next();
        match n {
            Some(Device) => return Some(LitraDevice{dev: n.unwrap()}),
            None => return None,
        }
    }
}
```

Now I really cannot figure out how to code `LitraDeviceIterator` so that it wraps the filtered iterator.
All code iterations I have tried so far turn into a generic nightmare very quickly.

Comment: You can't use a `dyn Foo` directly, it needs to be behind some kind of reference. Here you probably want `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = rusb::Device<rusb::GlobalContext>>>`

Comment: Can't find `LitraDevice` on the internet, what is it? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. Further, `Self::can_not_handle` does not exist (seems quite important), and `LitraDeviceIterator` does not implement `Iterator`. Not sure how to help you with that much code missing.

Comment: I think I would know how to implement this in C++ using `decltype`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your `iter()` to yield `LitraDevice`, you can surely take it wherever you wanted to go from there.

The first underlying issue is that `filter()` yields references, but in cases like these, you actually mean to move yielded items while filtering. That's what `filter_map()` is capable of. That way, you can scrap the references, greatly simplifying your code.

(This code does not work yet, read on)

```rust
pub fn iter(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = LitraDevice> {
    self.unfiltered.iter().filter_map(|dev| {
        (!Self::can_not_handle(&dev))
            .then_some(dev)
            .map(|dev| LitraDevice { dev })
    })
}
```

Now, there's a second little issue at play her: `rusb::DeviceList<T : UsbContext>>::iter(&self)` returns `rusb::Devices<'_, T>`, `'_` being the anonymous lifetime inferred from `&self`. Meaning, while you can drive `rusb::Devices<'_, T>` to yield `Device<T>`s, you can not actually keep it around longer than `self.unfiltered`. More specifically, as you consume `self` in `iter()`, you can not return an iterator referencing that `rusb::Devices<'_, T>` from `iter()`. One solution is to immediately collect, then again moving into an iterator.

```rust
pub fn iter(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = LitraDevice> {
    let devices = self.unfiltered.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    devices.into_iter().filter_map(|dev| {
        (!Self::can_not_handle(&dev))
            .then_some(dev)
            .map(|dev| LitraDevice { dev })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation - learned a lot.